# passlib.hash import sha256_crypt gives error when compiled with py2exe

Tags: python, encryption, hash, sha256, pycrypto

I have a code written in Python where I am hashing the password using `passlib.hash`, `sha256_crypt` and then later verifying the password using the same library .

I am able to run the code using the console i.e. using `.py`.

My problem occurs when I compile this program using `py2exe`:

```
ImportError: No module named passlib.hash
```

I am importing the module using following command :

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
```

and sometimes I see a warning saying no module named`sha256_crypt` in the GUI but the program still runs correctly.

I am using Windows 7 and could not find any solution to this problem. I have checked my python home directory it seems on installing passlib-1.6.1 , `passlib-1.6.1-py2.7.egg` file is created under `C:\Python2.7.5\Lib\site-packages`, however there are no files named `passlib/hash` or `sha_256`.

Answer (score 3):

[Eli Collins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19639836/2993751) is actually right and pointed me in the right direction.

You can solve your problem by typing the import more specifically.
I solved my `sha512` problem by changing the import to be looking like this

```
from passlib.handlers.sha2_crypt import sha512_crypt
```

My `py2exe` distribution now works very well.

I know it's a little late for you, but it still might help someone, like it helped me. Kudos for having filed the question and also kudos to Eli!

Comment: I faced the same problem as OP and fixed it the same way you did. But I still wonder why the statement 
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt 
did not work.

Answer (score 2):

In order to load only the hashers which have been explicitly requested, Passlib plays a dynamic import trick: `passlib.hash` is actually a special object which only imports each hasher class *when requested* ... the real hasher classes are actually stored in modules over in passlib's internal package `passlib.handlers` (in particular, `passlib.hash:sha256_crypt` is actually stored under `passlib.handlers.sha2_crypt:sha256_crypt`).

Py2exe on the other hand try to be smart, and tries to walk your application's import tree, and only bundle the modules which are actually loaded. I find it frequently (and understandably) fouls up whenever it runs into a python package pulling dynamic import tricks (like the above). This ends up with the py2exe-packaged apps giving strange and hard to track down import errors.

I'm not positive this will fix your problem, but the easiest solution I know of is to tell py2exe to include the entire `passlib` package, and not bother trying to "guess" which parts should be included. This can be done by adding `"passlib"` to py2exe's `packages` option...

```
setup(
    # ... other stuff ...
    options={
            "py2exe":{
                    # ... other stuff ...
                    "packages": ["passlib"],
            }
    }
)
```

Comment: I have tried to do that but now py2exe fails because it cannot import passlib.